# django rest framework posting object with relations fails to create

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I cannot make the Django rest framework to create the object with dependency. In short here is the simplified configuration that works for other part update, remove and create Employee. But it fails when creating Case with ForeignKey to Employee.

**models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Case(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='cases_created')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class SCase (serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = SEmployeeList(required = True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Case
        fields = ('url', 'title', 'author', 'id')   
class SEmployee(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        cases_created = SCaseList(many=True, required=False)
        class Meta:
            model = models.Employee
            fields = ('url', 'firstName', 'lastName','cases_created', 'id')
```

**views.py**

```
class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SEmployee

class CaseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Case.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SCase
```

The issue is when I create the object case, that must have reference to author.

1. **Passing existing objects creates the Case and new employee**

POST

```
{"author":{"url":"http://localhost:8000/restbase/employee/23/",
           "firstName":"Mark",
           "lastName":"Hilton",
           "cases_created":[],
           "id":23},
 "title":"New Case"
}
```

2. **Passing only URL for and existing author fails because creating author fails.**

POST

```
{"author":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/restbase/employee/23/","title":"New Case"}
```

RESPONSE

```
{"author": [{"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data"]}]}
```

3. **Passing only URL as an field of author brings following resposne**

POST

```
{"author":{"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/restbase/employee/23/"},"title":"New Case"}
```

RESPONSE

```
{"author": [{"lastName": ["This field is required."], "firstName": ["This field is required."]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the investigation deeper there is a working solution. The author cannot be serialized.

```
class SCase (serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # removed line: author = SEmployeeList(required = True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Case
        fields = ('url', 'title', 'author', 'id')
```

I still do not know how to use detailed information and create depended element